# Passing Bindings to Child View Models and Updating Them

Tags: swift, swiftui

In swiftui in my primary view, I have an environment object for my app state (`AppState` class) which includes the user record. The idea being that there's just one user, and all views should share that one instance of the user class. So `AppState` is created in `@main` and passed down as an `environmentObject` to all views. My `AppState.user` is an `@Published` var instance of a `CurrentUser` class.

Some (most) subviews don't need the full `AppState` instance, but just need some data from it, like the `AppState.user` instance. And they need to be able to update the user instance. But here's where the smell comes in for me, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

I have a series of screens in my app - a section called "onboarding". This entire section needs to know about and update properties on the user - did she enter X, did she finish or skip the onboarding. So I need to pass the `AppState.user` to the onboarding view model:

```swift
OnboardingSection()
  .environmentObject(OnboardingSectionVM(user: $appState.user))
```

...where `OnboardingSectionVM.user` is `var user: Binding<User>`. Works great to read the current user. But now I want to update the user at the global `AppState` level, and to do so I'm writing this save function, and it feels dirty:

```swift
class OnboardingSectionVM: ObservableObject {
  var user: Binding<User>
  @Published var birthday: Date?

  init(currentUser: Binding<CurrentUser>) { ... }

  func save() {
    currentUser.wrappedValue.birthday = self.birthday
  }
}
```

Is this right? When updating a Bound variable like this, do I update the `wrappedValue` and will that notify all the other views listening to `AppState.user` that it has changed? It feels dirty, like I'm working *around* the binding to update the underlying value.

Comment: You should only use `Binding` for view properties. For the view model, you can simply pass the user by reference, and if the `User` is a ObservableObject with `@Published` properties setting the `birthday` on the user object will trigger a update for the UI as appropriate.

Comment: I tried this, but the onboarding section is loaded based on a combination of app state and user properties. I may show the login screen, or the tabview, or whatever based on app state and user property values. So I do need the user to be an @Published var on the app state and therefore passed by references as a binding.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?